# UI Bug in Banner Ad

Tags: bug, advertising

I think there is a bug somewhere here, you can see HTML code that should not be there.

Browser Safari, Version 7.0 (9537.71)
OS: 10.9 Build 13A598
Extension: None (sadly).

> [image]

Comment: Browser and OS?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. And it doesn't look like the HTML is from the actual page source. You probably have some extensions / add-ons that injects HTML code to websites?

Comment: Just loaded the question page and got the _same_ ad - not reproducing these results. Meaning it was either fixed, or is specific to your setup - do you have any user scripts installed? Add-ons? Extensions?

Comment: You have some malware causing this. Remove the malware from your machine and it will be fine. Good luck!

Comment: Well to be honest, I don't think so @shadowwizard but I appreciate the recommendation. Thank you!:)

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187858/152859) for example. **Something** is injecting HTML in your browser, you can try to View Source and see the fully injected HTML to debug it further. Anyhow, it's NOT the doing of Stack Overflow or its advertisers.

Comment: @shadowwizard please take a look at the update

Comment: So for some reason people believed that you had a malware when you were the first to spot the actual bug, and your post was poorly received. Here's an upvote for you.

Comment: @Antony Even though the assumption may be wrong, it's a reasonable one to make, this wouldn't be the first case of malware injecting ads on SO.

Comment: @Stijn But considering how this one is poorly received compared to the duplicate that is posted a day later, he deserves some sympathy, don't you think?

Comment: @Antony yep, I'm to blame though I've never downvoted this one. I stand corrected and since the newer report got the official attention marking as dupe too.

Comment: @HerrK do you still see it happening? According to SE team that ad should be "paused".

Comment: Hey guys, no and I closely watch the ads. Regarding to @stijn; reasonable would be when the "diagnose" would have been done correctly. I myself thought that this could/should be malware but given the reason that I carefully inspected my browser I came to the conclusion that this was in fact, no malware. The easy diagnose would have been malware but the right questions were not asked in this case. It's encouraging to see some smiling faces in the community :) Happy Friday Everyone!