# New Ad feature? Extremely annoying

Tags: discussion, advertising, virus

Lately I have noticed a very annoying new feature on SO. I look for information, maybe find something, go someplace else and after a while the page redirects to a full screen advert for some online game or another. It took me a while to even realize this was coming from stackoverflow.
I can deal with banner ads and even maybe the occasional interstitial, provided I can just close it without getting redirected anyways, but this is really annoying, firstly because it is done in a really sneaky way, but secondly, because it makes ME look bad. I am using SO to investigate a work related problem and when I come back and a colleague looks at my screen, he sees some page related to online games. Not a huge deal at my company, but I would imagine more than one person getting a nasty remark for that.

Comment: Scan your computer for any malicious software, SE doesn't use any full screen ads.

Comment: Particularly look out for things that target your browser. Check for unexpected toolbars etc. You can verify it's a browser thing by using a different one (preferably one not currently installed on your machine - in case the malware targets **all** installed browsers).

Comment: Similar case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187858/in-text-adverts

Answer (score 18):

This is not something that is coming from Stack Overflow.

We do not allow full page ads, we do not have interstitials. We have 3 locations for ads and we require that they are not animated and do not use flash. We hate such ads just as much as you do.

What you describe can come from a few different sources, in our experience:

- Adware installed on your browser/computer. Could be a rogue toolbar.
- An ISP injecting ads into all http traffic.

Again - this is not something that we do.

Comment: good to know. I will investigate further then.